# Parallel running of 2 different program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, parallel-processing

I am calling a different program using button but as i pressed the button to run that program, the current running program pauses until the called program complete its execution. I want to keep the current execution running and even i want to run the called program. Is the parallel execution is possible.Please have a look at sample code, here i want to run the current program(keeps updating for every second) and the new_file program (which pop-up when the button is pressed ) parallely. Please let me know if any other information is needed. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import os
import threading
import random


def callback():
    filename = 'new_file.py'
    os.system(filename) 

def view(): 
    treeview.delete(*treeview.get_children())
    n = random.random()
    for i in range(5):
        treeview.insert('', 'end', value=n)
    threading.Timer(1.0, view).start()
    

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="Python File", command=callback).grid(row=0,column=0)

cols = ('name','number')
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols)
        
for col in cols:
    treeview.heading(col, text=col)
    treeview.column(col,minwidth=0,width=170)
        
treeview.grid(row=1, column=0)

view()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for your **`callback()`** function

```py
def callback():
    filename = 'new_file.py'
    thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: os.system(filename))
    thread.start()# start new thread
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work in a **`[PARALLEL]`** fashion, since Python interpreter uses since ever the central, monopolistic GIL-lock so as to **prevent** ( i.e. ***AVOID*** ) any kind or form of **`[PARALLEL]`** code / programs execution - Once the GIL-lock acquisition re-aligns the re-**`[SERIAL]`**-ised execution of any code so as to never ever even try to perform a single step in other but GIL-lock interleaved **`[SERIAL]`** execution ( one-BLOCK-after-another-BLOCK-after-another-BLOCK-after-...-...- ). So a `thread.Thread()`-based code execution is always a pure-sequential, not parallel.